# Can the background of an LCD be changed?

Tags: glcd

I recently bought a pair of these [128x64 graphical LCDs](https://www.winstar.com.tw/es/products/graphic-lcd-display-module/monochrome-graphic.html)

[image: 128x64 graphical LCDs]

They do look really good with that blue background, but then I saw this:

[image: black on white LCD]

And I started to wonder if it was possible to get that black on white look on my LCD. So, I decided to disassemble the metal shielding holding the actual glass. Now I know that the blue tint does not come from the backlight LED or the diffuser, but instead is something in the LCD itself:

[image: back of the LCD glass]

I would like to avoid peeling off all the different layers the LCD has until I find a blue one and then replace it with something else, so I would appreciate to get some information from someone who knows more about how LCDs are assembled, and if that blue tint can be changed.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just buy one that has the colors you want. You can get those modules in all sorts of configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, where I live, there is nothing like that black on white LCD, only blue or green on white, and I cant afford to buy it outside my country.

Comment: I know that the 2x16 or 5x20 LCDs come in various colors, some even support a changing backlight color, but that's not something one can change from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be due to a compensation film on the polarizers that increases the contrast by reducing light leakage through the 'off' sections.

For example, see this US patent [US7327422](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e6/a1/21/d919ec1c3c02f0/US7327422.pdf)

605 and 603 are  the compensation film layers, and are inserted between the back polarizer 613 and the back LCD glass 607 as well as the 603 film under the front polarizer 611.

[image]

Without access to those materials it is unlikely you could do much more than damage the LCD you have.